# python with selenium and chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
    for location in locations:
        for keyword in keywords:
            final_keyword = '{} in {}'.format(keyword, location)
            print('Searching businesses for', final_keyword)

            driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
            driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})

            driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/")

            search_el = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@aria-label="Search Google Maps"]')))
            search_el.send_keys(final_keyword)
            button_el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="searchbox-searchbutton"]')
            button_el.click()
```

please help, web **scraping** with selenium, python, and chrome driver but am getting an error when I run the script.

> DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57563/devtools/browser/21e41f80-b613-4344-b68f-07b7312c3abb
> [0225/101620.255:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3604)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: fail_if_major_perf_caveat + swiftshader
> [0225/101620.271:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3604)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: fail_if_major_perf_caveat + swiftshader

Message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Corel\Corel Content\win\google_maps_scraper-17-12-2020\script.py", line 139, in 
> business_el = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@aria-label, "Results for ")]/a[{}]'.format(index))))
> File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Corel\Corel Content\win\google_maps_scraper-17-12-2020\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 77, in until
> time.sleep(self._poll)

Comment: can you provide your sample code ? It has to visualize only with the error message

Comment: I have added a sample code